# Redirecting multiple URLs to different subdirectories on a single host (using htaccess?)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

*I apologise in advance as I feel that this might be a generic request that has been previously covered, however I haven't quite found the specific solution I'm looking for in my searches so far.*

I currently have 4 domains with one provider. e.g. www.domaina.com, www.domainb.com, www.domainc.com and www.domaind.com.

As these are single page websites, I'd like these domains to point to 4 separate *subdirectories* on a single host. Not sure if this is correct terminology, but this host doesn't have a domain associated with it, i.e. accessing the root directory just looks something like **69.195.124.72/~user/**.

e.g. What I'm after is:

- www.domaina.com -> 69.195.124.72/~user/a/
- www.domainb.com -> 69.195.124.72/~user/b/
- www.domainc.com -> 69.195.124.72/~user/c/
- www.domaind.com -> 69.195.124.72/~user/d/

Currently, the way I have this configured is that if a user types in www.domaina.com, they are redirected via a 301 configured on the host to 69.195.124.72/~user/a/. However, I want them to only see www.domaina.com as the address.

As far as I understand, there is only one .htaccess file which is located in the root directory of 69.195.124.72/~user/. I'm not sure what rules to add to this file to make this all happen at all.

I believe the most luck I've had is with something like:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domaina\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domaina.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^domaina\.com$ /69.195.124.72/~user/a/ [L]
```

But that seems to have resulted in a *website redirect loop* error when I've then tried to access www.domaina.com.

Is there any way to achive what I'm trying to here? Any help would be massively appreciated - thanks.

Comment: With no .htaccess, if you access domaina.com what happens does it change to the IP or does it show the content of what is inside ~user?

Comment: At the moment, if I access domaina.com I get the contents of /69.195.124.72/~user/a/ via a 301 configured on the domain server. This is the correct directory to be displayed, but I want the URL to still show domaina.com

Comment: Wow really your hosting company does not show your domain? You should change immediately. That's the worst configuration I ever seen, a host that replaces the client's domain with the user directory and ip. The last time I heard a hosting company providing the `~user` folder as home was around 2000

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood something but the host and domain are separate companies and I'm trying to set up domains to point to sub-directories on the host. Maybe I'm going around this the wrong way, but is this a setting I should be changing _on the domain provider_?

Comment: Then setup the DNS of your domain on the domain provider to point to your host and solve all your issues at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should note that I solved this problem by assigning **add-on domains** to each of the sub-directories and reconfiguring the DNS records.